# Adding TimePicker through plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

is there any way to add a DatePicker to settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't add time picker in the iOS settings.
There is no option for adding the TimePicker using the `settings.bundle root plist`.

Please check the [Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

These are the major option provided for the settings.

> **Text field**
>
> The text field type displays a title (optional) and an editable text
>   field. You can use this type for preferences that require the user to
>   specify a custom string value.
>
> The key for this type is **PSTextFieldSpecifier**.
>
> **Title**
>
> The title type displays a read-only string value. You can use this
>   type to display read-only preference values. (If the preference
>   contains cryptic or nonintuitive values, this type lets you map the
>   possible values to custom strings.)
>
> The key for this type is **PSTitleValueSpecifier**.
>
> **Toggle switch**
>
> The toggle switch type displays an ON/OFF toggle button. You can use
>   this type to configure a preference that can have only one of two
>   values. Although you typically use this type to represent preferences
>   containing Boolean values, you can also use it with preferences
>   containing non-Boolean values.
>
> The key for this type is **PSToggleSwitchSpecifier**.
>
> **Slider**
>
> The slider type displays a slider control. You can use this type for a
>   preference that represents a range of values. The value for this type
>   is a real number whose minimum and maximum value you specify.
>
> The key for this type is **PSSliderSpecifier**.
>
> **Multivalue**
>
> The multivalue type lets the user select one value from a list of
>   values. You can use this type for a preference that supports a set of
>   mutually exclusive values. The values can be of any type.
>
> The key for this type is **PSMultiValueSpecifier**.
>
> **Group**
>
> The group type is for organizing groups of preferences on a single
>   page. The group type does not represent a configurable preference. It
>   simply contains a title string that is displayed immediately before
>   one or more configurable preferences.
>
> The key for this type is **PSGroupSpecifier**.
>
> **Child pane**
>
> The child pane type lets the user navigate to a new page of
>   preferences. You use this type to implement hierarchical preferences.
>   For more information on how you configure and use this preference
>   type, see “Hierarchical Preferences.”
>
> The key for this type is **PSChildPaneSpecifier**.

Comment: thnx alot and why my settings are not being implemented?

Comment: how did you implementing the settings ? what are you doing in the viewDidLoad ?

Comment: I have implemented the settings using settings bundle.....now I am accessing it using NSUserDefaults in my viewDidload method....

Comment: NSString *favecolor=[defaults stringForKey:@"fave_color"];
    if ([favecolor isEqualToString:@"red"]) self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    if ([favecolor isEqualToString:@"green"]) self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    if ([favecolor isEqualToString:@"blue"]) self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    if ([favecolor isEqualToString:@"white"]) self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: issue is that my settings are implemented only after i restart the app.
So I want to know that it's a default behaviour or something is wrong in the code.

Comment: No, settings will be implemented at the time of installation, try with installing the ipa